# telnet counterpart for UDP

Tags: vpn, openvpn, testing, udp

Is there anything that enables a "telnet-like" functionality for UDP? I know the difference between TCP and UDP, and why telnet itself won't work - but I'm wondering if there is something similar to the telnet client, from the end-user perspective. E.g. udp-telnet [ip] [sending-port] [receiving-port] which then prints out wether a packet made it back or not.

Having a tool like this would proove helpful for testing out firewall settings for OpenVPN which uses UDP connections.

Comment: Note that by the very nature of UDP, it's impossible for a client to know whether a packet was delivered -- the server does not send an acknowledgement of received data on the protocol level.

Comment: Also note that in UDP, order of delivery is not guaranteed. That means that the following packets: "cd /". "cd temp", "rm -rf *" could lead to results you might not expect or enjoy. The way routing works, it's likely that the first packet arrives after the second and possibly third--the first often gets held up for a few seconds while routes are resolved--other packets can slip by before it's requeued.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use netcat - just start it, and type something inside, and pres the return key.

```
nc -u <host> <port>
```

And on the other side you can listen with netcat too (you should see the written text), or just start a tcpdump, and see packets coming in.

Comment: On the other side you could use : `tcpdump 'port <port>'` don't forget to type some messages after starting nc -u on the client !

Answer (score 15):

You can use `netcat` or `nc`. It supports TCP and UDP. Use the `-u` for UDP sockets. You can read `man nc` for more details.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows, I use PortQry for this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148